# Manifest.xml class or interface expeсted

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

Не получается получить  класс даже в новом проекте, полная переустановка не помогла. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что-то у вас поломалось, видать. Попробуйте студию переустановить

Comment: покажите MainActivity

Comment: Студия была переустановлена 2 раза.
Через .MainActivity не получается. 
Сделал правку по MainActivity.

Comment: У вас оба скриншота одинаковые.

Answer (score 1):

Просто `android:name=".MainActivity"` без имени пакета, но обязательно с точкой в начале.

Comment: Так не получается.

Comment: Что значит "не получается"? Какую ошибку выдаёт?

Comment: class or interface expeсted

Comment: Пробовали выполнить `Tools → Android → Sync Project with Gradle Files`, `Build → Clean Project` и `File → Invalidate Caches` ?

Comment: Не помогло. Уже и не знаю что делать.